# How to rename multiple file names in python

Tags: python, glob

I want to rename multiple files in a folder as they

The current filename as follows:

```
3321_AD_axial_001_MRI.jpg

3421_AD_axial_098_MRI.jpg

3521_AD_axial_032_MRI.jpg
```

The expected filename as follows:

**images0001.jpg,
images0002.jpg,
images0003.jpg**

filepath = "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/SVM-Image-Classification-master/test"

```
import os 
def main(): 
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir("test"): 
        dst ="images" + str(i) + ".jpg"
        src ='test'+ filename 
        dst ='test'+ dst 
        i += 1
        os.rename(scr,dst)
main()

ileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-840511576fe7> in <module>()
     18 
     19     # Calling main() function
---> 20     main()

<ipython-input-47-840511576fe7> in main()
     11         # rename() function will
     12         # rename all the files
---> 13         os.rename(src, dst)
     14         i += 1
     15 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test0543_AD_axial_099_PET.jpg' -> 'testimage0.jpg'
```

The function generated errors and all filenames stayed the same. They didn't change as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: change '`test'` to `'test/'`. Also, there is a typo in your `os.rename`. It should be `os.rename(src, dst)`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
import os 
def main(): 
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir("test"): 
        dst ="images_" + str(i) + "_.jpg"
        src = filename 
        path = "test/"+src
        newpath = "test/"+dst
        os.rename(path,newpath)
        i += 1
main()
```